# Traverse tree initializing variables

Tags: c#, recursion, tree

*If you find a more appreapiate way of naming the title of this question please feel free to update it.*

I have the Node

```
public Class Node
{
    public List<Node> Children = new List<Node>();
    public Node Parent;
    public FileSystemInfo Value;
}
```

to represent a file in a tree.

Now I will like to change that node class for:

```
class ScanItem
{
    public List<ScanItem> Children; 
    public ScanItem Parent;

    public long Size;
    public string Name;    
    public string FullPath;
    public bool IsDirectory;
    // etc....    

}
```

**So my question is** how will I be able to cast a `Node` class object to a `ScanItem`. **I will like to store the size of files and directories not just files.** (Node class only stores sizes of files not directories) Therefore I will have to somehow recursively keep track of the sum of the sizes of children in order to achieve what I want.

So far I have placed this constructor on ScanItem:

```
    public ScanItem(Node node)
    {                        
        this.Name = node.Name;
        this.FullPath = node.Value.FullName;

        foreach(var child in node.Children)
        {
             this.Children.add(new ScanItem(child));
        }
    }
```

That will enable me to perform the cast but I am missing to assign the sizes of directories...

Comment: `node.Name,node.FullName` I can't see these attributes in `Node`

Comment: fix it. that is not important though. I am initializing other variables in the constructor too. the only variable I am interested with is Size when it comes to directories...

Comment: why dont you iterate through all child files to calculate total size..even in OS they determine folder size the very time you query for its size.

Comment: Just a thought: if `node.Children` is empty in the constructor then you hit a leaf, so first set `this.Size = (node.Value is FileInfo) ? ((FileInfo)node.Value).Length : 0` and then "bubble add" the size up to the root with `ScanItem tmp = this; while (tmp.Parent != null) { tmp.Parent.Size += tmp.Size; tmp = tmp.Parent; }`

Comment: yeah I like that idea. I will fire the buble event every time I add a new file. There where a lot of events though. I am 10 levels down (hight of 10) and then plan to add 1000 files to that directory then I will be performing 1000*10 events...

Answer (score 1):

To get the size of a directory you can use this extension method

```
public static class DirectoryInfoEx
{
    public static long GetDirectorySize(this DirectoryInfo di)
    {
        long size = 0;

        var fileInfos = di.GetFiles();
        foreach (var fi in fileInfos)
        {
            size += fi.Length;
        }

        var subDirInfos = di.GetDirectories();
        foreach (var subDir in subDirInfos)
        {
            size += GetDirectorySize(subDir);
        }

        return size;
    }
}
```

If I got this correctly, you will just need to add two lines of code in the constructor of the `ScanItem` class

```
public ScanItem(Node node)
{                        
    this.Name = node.Name;
    this.FullPath = node.Value.FullName;
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(this.FullPath);  //<<<<<<<
    this.Size = di.GetDirectorySize();                    //<<<<<<<

    foreach(var child in node.Children)
    {
         this.Children.add(new ScanItem(child));
    }
}
```

You may need to handle some exceptional situations like `UnauthorizedAccessException`. You can also improve your style by getting rid of *public fields*, for example by converting them into *public auto properties* `public long Size{get;set;}`.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the help. That works but I will be finding the files twice thus making the algorithm twice as slow. I forgot to mention that I run a recursive method in order to find all the files and directories and return a Node object with it's corresponding children.

Comment: If you do something twice - cache it. The basic cache would be a dictionary with id of your choice and value that is going to be reused. You loose some memory, but gain performance.